# Qt off/on button

Tags: qt, виджет

Привет всем. Есть задача, нужно сделать Qt виджет как на картинке:

[image: Imgur]

QML не катит. Какие у кого идеи? Есть идея наследоваться от `QSlider`, переопределить `paintEvent`, задать `minValue = 0 maxValue = 1`? Еще можно попробовать наследоваться от `QCheckBox`, но тут тоже вопрос, добавление "бегунка" тот который будет делать вкл.\выкл.

Comment: qml не катит это вывод по возможности использования или условие задачи?

Comment: это условие

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доброго времени суток!

Возможно я не прав, но на мой взгляд проблема решается вот каким способом:

1) Наследуемся от `QAbstractButton` или от `QCheckBox`. От чего именно надо подумать, так  как у `QCheckBox` три состояния ("выделено", "не выделено", "частично выделена" см. `enum Qt::CheckState`) и это придется как-то обрабатывать. Я бы все-таки отнаследовался от `QAbstractButton`.

2) Переопределить `paitEvent(QPaintEvent*)` в любом случае. Сделать свое рисование  и желательно используя QPalette.

3) Анимацию я бы предложил сделать таким образом:

а) Создаем приватный класс наследованный от QObject (для QPropertyAnimation). Очень хорошо для этого подходит идиома Pointer To Implemetation (макросы `Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE` и `Q_D`). При этом придется создать отдельный заголовочный файл с суффиксом `_p` (например `mybutton_p.h`) для правильной работы MOC. Такой подход часто используется в самой библиотеке Qt. Более подробно [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/76248/) и [здесь](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Dpointer).

б) Объявляем и реализуем в приватном классе все необходимые свойства (позиция слайдера, текст и проч.) при этом надо учесть что при изменении некоторых свойств необходимо перерисовывать сам виджет.

в) Создаем в приватном классе слот, например, `void animate(bool)`. Параметр этого слота будет индикатором в какую сторону проигрывать анимацию.

г) Реализуем слот, используя QPropertyAnimation. Тут можно использовать enum Direction для правильного направления проигрывания и использовать qreal для интерполяции текущего положения бегунка (например 0.0 - крайнее левое(состояние "off"), 1.0 - крайнее правое (состояние "on").

д) Соединяем слот `void animate(bool)` нашего приватного класса c сигналом `clicked(bool)` основного класса. Это можно сделать в конструкторе основного класса.

В заключении можно предложить порыскать по всяким ресурсам - может, кто-то уже пытался реализовать что-то подобное. Во всяком случае это может натолкнуть на какие-то мысли или идеи.

Успехов!

**UPD:** реализовал ради интереса - на все ушло примерно час работы. Вот что получилось:

В состоянии выкл:
[image: SlideSwitchOff]

В состоянии вкл:
[image]

Ссылка на проект на SourceForge: https://sourceforge.net/projects/qslideswitcher/

Ссылка на исследование: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/research/289306/widgets-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-qt-off-on-button-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-qml

Comment: Поделитесь кодом, пожалуйста. Если не жалко :)

Comment: У меня предложение: может создать исследование? Просто кода довольно много для ответа, да и хотелось бы как-то более развернуто ответить что ли... А то здесь мне кажется как-то громоздко получится) А кодом я поделюсь без вопросов - там ничего хитрого))

Comment: "Просто кода довольно много для ответа, да и хотелось бы как-то более развернуто ответить что ли..." +1

Можете куда-нибудь залить код, если не сложно?

Comment: Эх... ни разу не пробовал пользоваться SourceForge и проч. Вот и попробую) Просто не знаю насколько быстро там разберусь) В крайнем случае на файлообменник залью) Пометьте  пока ответ как правильный) Да, исследование то создаем?

Comment: Какова суть исследования? Я просто тут недавно. Я так понимаю это более менее широко развернут вопрос (ответ на вопрос). Давайте создадим, думаю тема может пригодиться еще не одному.

Comment: Хорошо) Я на SourceForge создал проект с исходным кодом - вот ссылка: https://sourceforge.net/projects/qslideswitcher/

Просьба ногами не пинать - делал в первый раз в жизни)))

Comment: Добавил ссылку на исследование)

Answer (score 0):

если не учитывать тот вариант, где бегунок анимированный то задача решается обычным QCheckBox и qss стилями в противном случае, надо реализовывать руками механизм анимации.

Comment: Да, нужно учитывать анимацию. Как в этом случае тогда использовать checkbox? Как реализовывать механизм анимации, если через qss можно подставить имейджи для разных состояний? QPropertyAnimation не прикрутишь же? Я так понял рисовать новый виджет (или наследоваться от QCheckBox).